# How to use Compiler instance and ASTConsumer with clang 3.6

Tags: c++, clang++, llvm-clang

I have a little tool based on clang that create a compiler instance and that was able to parse C header files. This tool worked fine with clang 3.4 and 3.5.

I first created a compiler instance and use it with a new class created from an ASTConsumer:

```
ci = new clang::CompilerInstance()
ci.createDiagnostics();
ci.createFileManager();
ci.createSourceManager(ci.getFileManager());
std::shared_ptr<clang::TargetOptions> pto = std::make_shared<clang::TargetOptions>();
pto->Triple = llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple();
clang::TargetInfo *pti = clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(m_ci.getDiagnostics(), pto);
ci.setTarget(pti);
ci.createPreprocessor(clang::TU_Complete);
...     
//add source file and the headers paths
...
MyASTConsumer * myASTConsumerClassInstance = new MyASTConsumer;
ci.setASTConsumer(myASTConsumerClassInstance);
...
//parse the header file
```

where myASTConsumerClassInstance is an instance of the class that I created like this (a simplified form):

```
class MyASTConsumer : public clang::ASTConsumer
{
    MyASTConsumer()
    ~MyASTConsumer() {};
    virtual bool HandleTopLevelDecl( clang::DeclGroupRef d);
    virtual void HandleTagDeclDefinition( clang::TagDecl * d);
    private:
    std::vector<clang::TagDecl *> m_my_tags;
}
```

In the `HandleTagDeclDefinition` method, all the tags declarations where registred in the vector `m_my_tags`. So after the parsing process, I was able to access to all the tag declarations from myASTConsumerInstance.

Now in the clang 3.6 api, the method `clang::CompilerInstance::setASTConsumer` requiert a `std::unique_ptr<ASTConsumer>`. How to adapt my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy in fact replace this

```
MyASTConsumer * myASTConsumerClassInstance = new MyASTConsumer;
ci.setASTConsumer(myASTConsumerClassInstance);
```

with :

```
ci.setASTConsumer(llvm::make_unique<MyASTConsumer>());
```

or :

```
MyASTConsumer * myASTConsumerClassInstance = new MyASTConsumer;
ci.setASTConsumer(llvm::make_unique<clang::ASTConsumer>(*myASTConsumerClassInstance));
```